# Google sheet: Replace (_) with (Empty space) in the selected cells

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I need to replace the (_) in the first range (Red rectangle) into a SPACE in the second range (Green rectangle).
How can i do that ? thanks in advance ❤️

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10; "_"; " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also works:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"_"," "))
```

Comment: Gonna try that and let u know if it wokes or not, thanks for your help